# Run time Error, Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro to generate a data and it was working initially however, now it is giving an error, "subscipt out of range". Please I need assistance:

```
 Sub paste()
'
' paste Macro
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent").Visible = True
    Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent").Select
    Columns("B:P").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & "\Raw_Data_Agent.xls"
    Columns("A:O").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Real Time Agent AHT And Login Tracker").Activate
    Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
    Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent").Visible = False
    Workbooks("Raw_Data_Agent").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Sheets("AM And Process Wise").Select
    Calculate
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does this script break?

Comment: Workbooks("Real_Time_Agent_AHT_And_Login_Tracker").Activate

Comment: Workbooks("Real_Time_Agent_AHT_And_Login_Tracker").Activate, the line breaks here

Answer (score 0):

I would place my bet on one of the sheet names not being accurate. OR the focus moving to the wrong workbook. And hence you should avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Your code can be re-written as (UNTESTED)

```
Sub paste()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook, AnotherWb as Workbook
    Dim thisWs As Worksheet
    Dim nCalc

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        nCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlManual
    End With

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent")
    Set AnotherWb  = Workbooks("Real Time Agent AHT And Login Tracker")

    MyPath = thisWb.Path

    With thisWs
        .Visible = True
        .Columns("B:P").ClearContents

        Set thatWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\Raw_Data_Agent.xls")

        thatWb.Columns("A:O").Copy AnotherWb.Sheets("Raw_Data_Agent").Range("B1")

        .Visible = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        thatWb.Close False
    End With

    thisWb.Sheets("AM And Process Wise").Calculate
    thisWb.RefreshAll

LetsContinue:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = nCalc
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Also when you are working with events, always use error handling else if you get an error, those events are not restored to defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, when I try to run the code line by line, this is where the issue is exactly:  Workbooks("Real_Time_Agent_AHT_And_Login_Tracker").Activate

Comment: I just amended the code and if you get an error on the line `Set AnotherWb  = Workbooks("Real Time Agent AHT And Login Tracker")` then that means it cannot find the workbook with that name.